# Interpreting $x_1\left(x_5 - x_3 \right) = \left(x_2 - x_1 \right)\left(x_3 + x_4 \right)$ Geometricaly

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $x_1,\ x_2,\ x_3,\ x_4,\ x_5 \in \mathbb{R^*}$ such that

$$\frac{x_1}{x_2} = \frac{x_3}{x_4} = \frac{x_4}{x_5}$$

Then I have to prove the following statement

$$x_1\left(x_5 - x_3 \right) = \left(x_2 - x_1 \right)\left(x_3 + x_4 \right)$$

Is there any geometrical interpretation of this problem?

Comment: What does $~\Bbb{R^*}~$ signify$\,$? Also, are you asking how to prove the equation algebraically, or are you (instead) only asking if there is some geometric significance to the algebraic equation$\,$?

Comment: Thanks @user2661923 for your contributation **\Bbb{R^*}** is the set of non-zero real numbers. I Already know a prove of this equality. I'm interested on a geometric interpretation.